# JSoup create array list from elements list

Tags: java, jsoup

so I am grabbing a BIG list of elements using JSoup from a page. When I say big, I mean like a few hundred elements. I know that the elements are there because I converted them all to one huge string and they were all listed. Now what I need to do is put them into an array so I can process them 1 by 1. Here is my current code:

```
    public static String [] grabWordList(String ending) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.com/").get();
Elements links = doc.getElementsByClass("defLink"); //Get words from site
String s[] = new String[links.size()]; //Create an array

int i = 0;
for(Element el : links){  //Attempt to put them into an array using this loop of blindly coppy and pasted code (I know, HORRIBLE Idea, I dont usually do that, but I am lost)
    s[i++] = el.attr("links");
}
 return s;
    }
```

When I do this, I use this code to attempt to grab the array and print it:

```
String words[] = Methods.grabWordList("in");

   for(int j=0; j < words.length; j++){
       System.out.println(words[j]);
   }
```

When running this code, all that prints is `[Ljava.lang.String;@6201dbc`
Im hoping that someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;@...` means you're trying to use an array of String where you should be using a String. You will want to extract the Strings from that array before adding. e.g., `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(words[j]));`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If I extract the Strings from the array will it not be an array anymore?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels And after trying that line of code, I get this error 'no suitable method found for toString(java.lang.String)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think, "String words[]" words should be defined as "String []", like in Java creating an array.but I'm not too skilled for JSoup.